# Illegal output or inout port connection for port 'next_key'

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to SIMULATE my design, but I get this error:

> Illegal output or inout port connection for port 'next_key'.

although I connected `wire` to `output reg`. I have tried to change 'next_key' as `output wire`  and made `round_counter` `reg` and `wire`.

I have even tried to make `wire` the index variable. I think i tried every possibility.

Here is the module :

```
module keygen (
    input clock,
    input startTransition,
    input [127:0] roundKeyInput,
  
    output reg [127:0] roundKeyOutput1,
    output reg [127:0] roundKeyOutput2,
    output reg [127:0] roundKeyOutput3,
    output reg [127:0] roundKeyOutput4,
    output reg [127:0] roundKeyOutput5,
    output reg [127:0] roundKeyOutput6,
    output reg [127:0] roundKeyOutput7,
    output reg [127:0] roundKeyOutput8,
    output reg [127:0] roundKeyOutput9,
    output reg [127:0] roundKeyOutput10,
    output reg [127:0] roundKeyOutput0
  );
  
  
  reg [127:0] tempKeys [0:10];
  wire [127:0] round_out [1:10];
  reg [3:0] round_counter ; //to be able to increment
  wire [3:0] round_counter_wire;
  
  
  reg [3:0] state;
  reg [3:0] IDLE                    = 4'd0;
  reg [3:0] START_CREATE_ROUNDKEY   = 4'd1;
  reg [3:0] STOP_CREATE_ROUNDKEY    = 4'd2;
  reg [3:0] STOP                    = 4'd3;
  
  initial
  begin
  
    state = 4'd0;
    round_counter=4'd0;  
    roundKeyOutput1  = 128'd0;
    roundKeyOutput2  = 128'd0;
    roundKeyOutput3  = 128'd0;
    roundKeyOutput4  = 128'd0;
    roundKeyOutput5  = 128'd0;
    roundKeyOutput6  = 128'd0;
    roundKeyOutput7  = 128'd0;
    roundKeyOutput8  = 128'd0;
    roundKeyOutput9  = 128'd0;
    roundKeyOutput10 = 128'd0;
    roundKeyOutput0 = 128'd0;
  
    tempKeys[0]  = 128'd0;
    tempKeys[1]  = 128'd0;
    tempKeys[2]  = 128'd0;
    tempKeys[3]  = 128'd0;
    tempKeys[4]  = 128'd0;
    tempKeys[5]  = 128'd0;
    tempKeys[6]  = 128'd0;
    tempKeys[7]  = 128'd0;
    tempKeys[8]  = 128'd0;
    tempKeys[9]  = 128'd0;
    tempKeys[10] = 128'd0;
  end
  
  
  keygenround round_key(
    .initial_key(tempKeys[round_counter_wire]), //input
    .clk(clock),
    .enable(startTransition),
    .round(round_counter),
/*****************************************************///here is the error 
    .next_key(round_out[round_counter_wire+4'd1]) // output reg
  );


  assign round_counter_wire = round_counter;
  
  always @(posedge clock)
  begin
    case (state)
       IDLE: begin
         if (startTransition==1) begin
            tempKeys[0]=roundKeyInput;
            roundKeyOutput0=roundKeyInput;
            state= START_CREATE_ROUNDKEY;
         end
       end 
       START_CREATE_ROUNDKEY : begin
            if (round_counter<4'd10) begin
                if (round_counter<4'd10 && round_counter> 4'd1) tempKeys[round_counter]=round_out[round_counter];
                round_counter= round_counter+1;
                state= START_CREATE_ROUNDKEY;
            end else begin
              state = STOP_CREATE_ROUNDKEY;
            end
       end
       STOP_CREATE_ROUNDKEY : begin
        roundKeyOutput1=tempKeys[1];
        roundKeyOutput2=tempKeys[2];
        roundKeyOutput3=tempKeys[3];
        roundKeyOutput4=tempKeys[4];
        roundKeyOutput5=tempKeys[5];
        roundKeyOutput6=tempKeys[6];
        roundKeyOutput7=tempKeys[7];
        roundKeyOutput8=tempKeys[8];
        roundKeyOutput9=tempKeys[9];
        roundKeyOutput10=tempKeys[10];
         
       end

        default: begin
          state =IDLE;
    
        end 
    endcase



  end
endmodule
```

`keygenround` module portmap:

```
module keygenround(
    input [127:0] initial_key,
    input clk,
    input enable,
    input [3:0] round,
    output reg [127:0] next_key

);
```

EDIT: Here is the simulation code:

```
module keygen_tb;


reg clock50MHz;
reg startTransition;
reg  [127:0] inputKey;
reg  [127:0] expectedValue1;
reg  [127:0] expectedValue2;
reg  [127:0] expectedValue3;
reg  [127:0] expectedValue4;
reg  [127:0] expectedValue5;
reg  [127:0] expectedValue6;
reg  [127:0] expectedValue7;
reg  [127:0] expectedValue8;
reg  [127:0] expectedValue9;
reg  [127:0] expectedValue10;
reg  [127:0] expectedValue0;

wire [127:0] outputKey1;
wire [127:0] outputKey2;
wire [127:0] outputKey3;
wire [127:0] outputKey4;
wire [127:0] outputKey5;
wire [127:0] outputKey6;
wire [127:0] outputKey7;
wire [127:0] outputKey8;
wire [127:0] outputKey9;
wire [127:0] outputKey10;
wire [127:0] outputKey0;



 keygen dut (
    .clock              (clock50MHz),
    .startTransition    (startTransition),
    .roundKeyInput      (inputKey),
    .roundKeyOutput0    (outputKey0),
    .roundKeyOutput1    (outputKey1),
    .roundKeyOutput2    (outputKey2),
    .roundKeyOutput3    (outputKey3),
    .roundKeyOutput4    (outputKey4),
    .roundKeyOutput5    (outputKey5),
    .roundKeyOutput6    (outputKey6),
    .roundKeyOutput7    (outputKey7),
    .roundKeyOutput8    (outputKey8),
    .roundKeyOutput9    (outputKey9),
    .roundKeyOutput10   (outputKey10)
  );

// Creating the prameters required for the 50MHz clock, and the stoppage of the test bench. 
localparam NUM_CYCLES = 1000;
localparam CLOCK_FREQ = 50000000;
real HALF_CLOCK_PERIOD = (1000000000.0 / $itor(CLOCK_FREQ)) / 2.0;
integer half_cycle = 0; 


initial begin
    // Set input and expected values
    inputKey        = 128'h000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f;
    expectedValue0  = 128'h000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f;
    expectedValue1  = 128'hd6aa74fdd2af72fadaa678f1d6ab76fe;
    expectedValue2  = 128'hb692cf0b643dbdf1be9bc5006830b3fe;
    expectedValue3  = 128'hb6ff744ed2c2c9bf6c590cbf0469bf41;
    expectedValue4  = 128'h47f7f7bc95353e03f96c32bcfd058dfd;
    expectedValue5  = 128'h3caaa3e8a99f9deb50f3af57adf622aa;
    expectedValue6  = 128'h5e390f7df7a69296a7553dc10aa31f6b;
    expectedValue7  = 128'h14f9701ae35fe28c440adf4d4ea9c026;
    expectedValue8  = 128'h47438735a41c65b9e016baf4aebf7ad2;
    expectedValue9  = 128'h549932d1f08557681093ed9cbe2c974e;
    expectedValue10 = 128'h13111d7fe3944a17f307a78b4d2b30c5;

    startTransition = 0;
    clock50MHz = 0;
end

initial begin
    // Wait 500 clock cylces before setting the startTransition high.
   repeat(500) @ (posedge clock50MHz);  
   startTransition = 1;
end


always begin
    #(HALF_CLOCK_PERIOD);
    clock50MHz = ~clock50MHz;
    half_cycle = half_cycle + 1;
    
    if (half_cycle == (2 * NUM_CYCLES)) begin       
    
        // Comparing the acquired outputs with the expected outputs and printing
      // the corresponding message depending on the results.
        if((outputKey1 != expectedValue1) | (outputKey2  != expectedValue2)  |
            (outputKey3 != expectedValue3) | (outputKey4  != expectedValue4)  |
            (outputKey5 != expectedValue5) | (outputKey6  != expectedValue6)  |
            (outputKey7 != expectedValue7) | (outputKey8  != expectedValue8)  |
            (outputKey9 != expectedValue9) | (outputKey10 != expectedValue10) |
            (outputKey0 != expectedValue0)) begin 
            
            $display("Fail \n \n",
                        "For the following inputs: \n",
                        "Input Key: %h \n \n", inputKey,
                        "Expected output: \n",
                        "Output RoundKey 0: %h \n ", expectedValue0,
                        "Output RoundKey 1: %h \n", expectedValue1,
                        "Output RoundKey 2: %h \n", expectedValue2,
                        "Output RoundKey 3: %h \n", expectedValue3,
                        "Output RoundKey 4: %h \n", expectedValue4,
                        "Output RoundKey 5: %h \n", expectedValue5,
                        "Output RoundKey 6: %h \n", expectedValue6,
                        "Output RoundKey 7: %h \n", expectedValue7,
                        "Output RoundKey 8: %h \n", expectedValue8,
                        "Output RoundKey 9: %h \n", expectedValue9,
                        "Output RoundKey 10: %h \n\n", expectedValue10,
                        
                        "Aquired output: \n",
                        "Output RoundKey 0: %h \n ", outputKey0,
                        "Output RoundKey 1: %h \n", outputKey1,
                        "Output RoundKey 2: %h \n", outputKey2,
                        "Output RoundKey 3: %h \n", outputKey3,
                        "Output RoundKey 4: %h \n", outputKey4,
                        "Output RoundKey 5: %h \n", outputKey5,
                        "Output RoundKey 6: %h \n", outputKey6,
                        "Output RoundKey 7: %h \n", outputKey7,
                        "Output RoundKey 8: %h \n", outputKey8,
                        "Output RoundKey 9: %h \n", outputKey9,
                        "Output RoundKey 10: %h \n\n", outputKey10,
                        ,
                      );
        end
    
        if((outputKey1 == expectedValue1) | (outputKey2 == expectedValue2)   |
            (outputKey3 == expectedValue3) | (outputKey4 == expectedValue4)   |
            (outputKey5 == expectedValue5) | (outputKey6 == expectedValue6)   |
            (outputKey7 == expectedValue7) | (outputKey8 == expectedValue8)   |
            (outputKey9 == expectedValue9) | (outputKey10 == expectedValue10) |
            (outputKey0 == expectedValue0)) begin 
            
            $display("Pass \n \n",
                        "For the following inputs: \n",
                        "Input Key: %h \n \n", inputKey,
                        "Aquired output: \n",
                        "Output RoundKey 1: %h \n", outputKey1,
                        "Output RoundKey 2: %h \n", outputKey2,
                        "Output RoundKey 3: %h \n", outputKey3,
                        "Output RoundKey 4: %h \n", outputKey4,
                        "Output RoundKey 5: %h \n", outputKey5,
                        "Output RoundKey 6: %h \n", outputKey6,
                        "Output RoundKey 7: %h \n", outputKey7,
                        "Output RoundKey 8: %h \n", outputKey8,
                        "Output RoundKey 9: %h \n", outputKey9,
                        "Output RoundKey 10: %h \n", outputKey10,
                        "Output RoundKey 11: %h \n \n", outputKey0,
                      );
        end
        
        $stop;
    end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

I get a different, more detailed error message with the simulator I use:

```
    .next_key(round_out[round_counter_wire+4'd1]) // output reg
                                         |
xmelab: *E,NOTPAR : Illegal operand for constant expression [4(IEEE)].
```

It expects a constant expression (not a variable expression) as the part-select when connecting to a module output.

You can create a new wire, and connect the wire directly to the output:

```
  wire [127:0] round_out_temp = round_out[round_counter_wire+4'd1];

  keygenround round_key(
    .next_key (round_out_temp)
```

In general, avoid complex expressions when making module port connections.

The code compiles without errors on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/DAWP).